# How can I use config() function in the index.php file?

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel framework. I need to use `config()` function in the `index.php` file (which exists in the *public* folder). But when I call it, it throws this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function config() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\public\index.php on line 2

How can I fix it?

Comment: *I need to use config() function in the index.php* uh...? isn't `index.php` used to bootstrap everything, so it loaded even before `config()` helper loaded.. alternatively, you might interested in using [`$_ENV`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php)

Comment: Technically, config will be loaded somewhere in index.php (After $kernel->handle(), but I don't think it's the right place to make something of it. @stack, what are you triying to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll not be able to use `config()` in `index.php` if no functionality were loaded at this point.

What you can do is to create simple functionality which will load data you need from config file. Or you can just hardcode value in `index.php`. But I'd recommend you to find another way to achieve your goal and not touch `index.php` at all.

**Update**
Laravel has already have [maintenance mode](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#maintenance-mode) functionality.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is making a mode configuration for my website. When `$mode == 0`, user can visit my website as well, but when `$mode = 1`, it means developers are working on the website and users should be redirect to another file like `temporarily_closed.php`.

Comment: Laravel has already have the functionality which you can use. Please read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#maintenance-mode

Comment: Big Like `:-)` +1

Comment: Also please add your last comment to your answer as a note.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Config` facades may not introduce for this index.php. You add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;` to use `Config` method.

**UPDATE**
Instead of  `Config` Try `var_dump(getenv('APP_ENV'));`, will help to use environment variable.

Comment: I've tested your solution but still the error is there.